# How to remove a port bind still used by sshd after an improper deconnection from ssh?

Tags: ssh, port, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

> **Note:** this post is **not** a duplicate of [SSH remote port forwarding failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/595323/ssh-remote-port-forwarding-failed).
>   The question here is not **what** causes port forwarding (temporarily) failure, we know what it is. The question is **how** to remove the broken sshd port bind. Thank you.

I have a server A with a dynamic IP running autossh to maintain a reverse tunnel to a machine B with a static IP.
The following code works fine:

```
autossh -M 0 -q -N -R2222:localhost:22 -o ServerAliveInterval 60 -o   ServerAliveCountMax 3 -o ExitOnForwardFailure yes USER@B -p PORT
```

However, when the connection crashes due to an IP change of A, it takes a "long" time (say an hour) to recover the connection. That's because sshd from machine B still listens to port 2222, thus preventing ssh (from machine A) to bind port 2222 after the crash.

auth.log from B contains dozens of :

```
Accepted publickey for USER from A port SOMEPORT ssh2: ED25519 XXXXXXXX
error: bind: Address already in use
error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 2222
```

Till the connection is finally accepted without forward failure (causing autossh stops respawning ssh, as awaited) because sshd finally no more listens to port 2222.

How could I (at least manually) tell sshd (on machine B) it should no more listen to port 2222, so I can recover the connection without waiting an hour (and without restarting machine B) ?

PS: restarting sshd does not solve the issue.

PPS: `ExitOnForwardFailure yes` works for me even without the `=`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH remote port forwarding failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/595323/ssh-remote-port-forwarding-failed)

Comment: It hunky our need to configure `ClientAliveIntervall` and the ClientAliveCount values on the server side, too. Instead of restarting sshd you need to kill the sshd child which has the port open (you can use `Sido netstat -lnp` to get the pid)

Answer (score 2):

You also need to set timeout options on the *ssh server* so that it will drop the connection more quickly.

For example you might add to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```